Data Cloud service cost
I have been trying to understand how Salesforce charges for Data cloud services but haven't got any clear understanding. Below are the questions I am seeking clarity on.

If a data stream is configured using Snowflake Direct Access (with
acceleration) do all the records get reloaded into Data Cloud
everytime the acceleration runs. If so is cost incurred for all the
records everytime the acceleration runs. Or does the credit consumed
and the cost incurred calculated based on how many new records get
added or updated in the source object. I see the refresh history says full refresh for a
Snowflake stream.
For example if a Data Stream
is configured on Monday to ingest a Snowflake object using
acceleration schedule set to run daily and given the snowflake
object has 1 million records. The credit consumed for ingestion of
the object on Monday would be based on the 1 million records.
However when the acceleration runs on subsequent days say on Tuesday
, would the credit consumed and cost incurred depend
only for the records that have been updated and new records that
have been added or would it be for the entire dataset present in the
source object.

How is Snowflake Direct Access different from Direct
Access(acceleration) in terms of credits consumed and cost incurred.

Does the cost of running Data Transform depend on the number of
records in the source objects or does it depend on the records that have
been added or updated in the source object(s).
For example a Data
Transform is configured to run daily on a Snowflake (Direct Access) object initially having 1
million records.
Now total records processed under the data transform is 1 million on Day 1(when transform is configured initially)
Given each subsequent day, on an average 1K records get added or updated daily in the source object in Snowflake, Would the calculation of the number of credits consumed a day later be based on the 1k records or the total records in the source object.

Salesforce has provided breakup of how many credits get consumed for
each service ,eg 2000 credits for every 1 unit ingested(1 unit= 1
million).However, is there a standard proportion of how many credits
correspond to 1 dollar?

If say 5 Snowflake objects are ingested through Direct
Access(acceleration) and then they are transformed with the
transformed output being saved into a DLO, what all factors will be
contributing to the cost incurred. Would it be all of Batch Ingestion, Data
Federation and Data Transform?
If instead the objects are ingested using Direct Access(without acceleration) what services
will consume credits and incur
cost. Would it be only Data Federation and Data Transform?



Talk to your Salesforce and/or Snowflake Account Executives, their job is to answer these questions.


You can choose between Incremental Refresh (Upsert) or a Full Refresh for a Zero Copy source. Unfortunately an Incremental Refresh will not remove records.

Think of an Accelerated DLO like ingestion, and I believe the credit multiplier is Batch Data Pipeline, 2000 credits per million rows. Accessing via Query Federation (no acceleration) would be charged at 70 credits per million rows retrieved. So acceleration works well when you have high volumes of data or high frequency read scenarios, or both. This is half of it. It's also important to consider rows read on your Snowflake side, which will have costs of its own. Optimization on the Snowflake side is always a good idea. One thing I've seen that generally works well is Accelerate your Dimension tables, and use Zero Copy for your Fact Tables.

Data Transforms are charged at the higher rows processed between reads or writes.

Credit costs are highly dependent on volume discounts. Standard list rate is $0.01 per credit as of posting.

It could be more advantageous and readily accessible to transform at the source rather than in Data Cloud, but if you have to within Data Cloud, then you'd be paying for either Acceleration or Query Federation and then the higher end of Writes / Reads in rows processed on the Batch Transform. You can't stream transform Zero Copy sources.



Thank you for this explanation. If i understand correctly an accelerated data stream is actually the same as a batch ingested data stream? There is no direct external access even though it says that the stream type is Direct Access and the DLO type is External?
